# How to add a file to a .gz archive and delete the original file?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

My files name is <09/12/2020>_master. How would I be able to add this file to a .gz archive and then remove the original file?

Answer (score 1):

GZip isn't an archive format, it's a compression format.  A .gz file can only contain one compressed file; if you need to put more than one file in at a time, you'll need to pair it with an archive format (such as `tar`).

Comment: Yep, with the only caveat is you can add/include the content of multiple files in a single gzip archive, but the addition loses its separate identity.

Comment: How would I be able to do that?